# Passing information between multiple activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would love some help (newish to android).

I currently have 4 activities.The first three activities has EditText fields in them, and then the final activity displays all the information that has been entered up to now. Seems simple enough,right?

So after looking on this site I discovered the way to do this was to use putExtra() and getExtra();

This doesn't quite seem to work as all the things I add to the extras hashset are not available at the final activity. Any advice?

Thanks

code below for help

```
package com.example.smallchangebigloss;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EnterName extends Activity {
    private EditText edit;
    private  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_name);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);

    }

    public Bundle getExtras(){
        return extras;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.enter_name, menu);
    return true;
}

public void next(View view) {
    if (edit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Ut Oh!")
                .setMessage("Please enter your name.")
                .setNeutralButton("Try again", null).show();
    }
    else {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CurrentWeight.class);
        i.putExtra("name", edit.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}

```
 package com.example.smallchangebigloss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class CurrentWeight extends Activity {

```
private EditText edit;
private String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_weight);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    name = extras.getString("name");
    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.currentWeightEdit);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.current_weight, menu);
    return true;
}

public void next(View view) {
    if (edit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Ut Oh!")
                .setMessage("Please enter your current weight.")
                .setNeutralButton("Try again", null).show();
    }
    else {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GoalWeight.class);
        i.putExtra("name", name);
        i.putExtra("current", edit.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}

```
package com.example.smallchangebigloss;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

public class GoalWeight extends Activity {

```
private EditText edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_goal_weight);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    System.out.println(extras.containsKey("name"));
    extras.containsKey("current");



    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.currentWeightEdit);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.goal_weight, menu);
    return true;
}

public void next(View view) {
    if (edit.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Ut Oh!")
                .setMessage("Please enter your Goal Weight.")
                .setNeutralButton("Try again", null).show();
    }
    else {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Complete.class);
        i.putExtra("goal", edit.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

}

```
package com.example.smallchangebigloss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Complete extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

//         TextView current = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.completeCurrentMod);
//         current.setText("hi");
////         current.setText(extras.getString("current"));   These lines break it

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complete);
        System.out.println("name: " + extras.getString("name") + "Current weight: "
                + extras.getString("current") + "goal: " + extras.getString("goal"));//Only displaying last ones...bundle them everytime in each class?
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.complete, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: what are the types of those data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is you need to pass your values from one class to the other in each class. So in `GoalWeight` Activity you need to pass "name" and "current" values also.

So do the following when starting the next Activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Complete.class);
        i.putExtra("goal", edit.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("name", extras.getString("name"));
        i.putExtra("current", extras.getString("current"));
        startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you aren't attaching all of the `extras` to each new `Intent`. Since you create a new `Intent` in each `Activity`, as you need to be doing, you also need to attach all of the `extras` from the previous `Activities`. The easiest way is to create a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) then get this `Bundle` in each activity and add the new `extras` to the `Bundle` each time.

Another way you could do it so you don't have to keep track of `extras` or a `Bundle` in each is to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Just add the value to a new preference each time then get them all in the final `Activity`. That link has a good example of creating and getting the `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 1):

Here is roughly what your code is doing:

Activity 1:

```
Start with no extras
Create and save extra called "name"
```

Activity 2:

```
Read name out of extras
create and save extra called "current"
save the value of name
```

Activity 3:

```
Read the whole bundle of extras
Create and save extra called "goal"
//Do nothing with the whole bundle
```

Activity 4:

```
Read the whole bundle of extras
```

Inside of Activity 3 you are pulling the values out of extras but not "re-saving" them so that they get passed along to the final activity. So when you get to activity4 the only extra that you should have is `"goal"` because that is the only one that you added at the end of Activity3.

Comment: So is my way of thinking right and the only way to do it? 
Add Name to extras -> move to next activity.
pull name out of activity, add current and name to extras -> next activity...
etc?

Comment: @Programatt yep, you have to explicitly add each of the previous values to the new intent you are using to start the next activity.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Intent in each of your text entry Activities and starting your Complete Activity. 
The first time your Complete Activity instance is created you will get the Intent extra and depending upon which Activity fired, the intent from that Activity.

If your Complete Activity is destroyed and recreated it will have the intent only from the one that created it.

Now if  your Complete Activity is already created and running and you are firing intents from other Activity you should look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

```
 @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        // get your new intent data here
    }
```

As an aside, in a real world app you would not be your entry fields strewn across Activities, so I am assuming you are just trying things out, which is cool.

Answer (score 0):

In the first Activity, get the strings into a variable from the `EditText`.And

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), B.class);
in.putExtra("TAG", String);
startActivity(in);
```

In the second activity, get it by

```
Intent x = getIntent();
String variable = x.getStringExtra("TAG");
```

And so on..